# Linked Files instead of linked list

Tags: c, list, file, memory, linked-list

I have a linked list with time start and time end tuples. In each list, those tuples are not overlapping.
Now, instead of put those tuples in a list, I want them to be stored in a file.
So ever list should be now a file. On order to sort this files and go through every file, I have to know which file is next to a file. In oder words, how can I make a pointer to the next File, such as in a linked list.

```
    typedef struct List
{
  struct List *next;


} List;
```

but I don't want something like this, where I create the linked list first, and then put each list in a file, because I want to evade memory usage. like here

```
static void create_files(List* first){

List* tmp = first;
int partition_num = 1;

while(tmp != NULL){
    char filename[29];
    sprintf(filename, "Partitions%d/Partition%d.txt",partition_folder, partition_num);
    File* partition;
    partition= fopen(filename, "w");


    while(tmp->head != NIL){

        fprintf(partition,"[%d, %d) \n",ts,te);
        tmp->head= tmp->head->next;

    }
    list_num++;
    tmp=tmp->next;

}
```

More something like this

```
File* firstfile;
{ //adding data to this file}
File* second_file;
{ // adding data to this file}
firstfile ->next = second file;
```

So I want something like a linked file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking how to put an information of a file inside another file? Just print it there..

Comment: Sorry, but I think you should get some help to rephrase your question. As it stands, it is very hard to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Define it like this

```
struct FileLinkedList
{
    FILE * f;
    FileNode * next;
}
```

But you need to have some meta-data in the files, for example the first line in the file is the file-name of the next file or 0 to end

**A.txt**

```
B.txt
This is the first Node in the FileLinkedList
```

**B.txt**

```
0
This is the last Node in the FileLinkedList
```

**List**

```
{ [A.txt] }--> { [B.txt] }--> 0
```

Then define functions to generate the list for you

```
FileLinkedList* createFileLinkedList (char* file_name)
{
    char next_file[255];
    FileLinkedList* n,head = (FileLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(FileLinkedList));
    head->f = fopen(file_name);
    next_file = get_meta(head->f);
    init_reader(head->f);

    n = head;
    while (strcmp("0",next_file) != 0)
    {
        n->next = (FileLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(FileLinkedList));
        n = n->next;
        n->f = fopen(next_file);
        next_file = get_meta(head->f);
        init_reader(head->f);
    }

    return head;
}
```

Where `get_meta` is to read the first line we need

```
char* get_meta (FILE* f)
{
    char* m = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
    rewind(f);
    fgets(m, sizeof(m), f);
    return m;
}
```

And `init_reader` is to put the file cursor after the meta-data part

```
void init_reader (FILE* f)
{
    rewind(f);
    while(fgetc(f) != '\n');
}
```